# Import error in Multiprocessing file

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to process large file using python multiprocessing module. While execution of below code I'm getting module import error. 
On python2.7 console, "from multiprocessing import Pool" is working fine.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import subprocess

def process_line(file):
    return "foo"

if __name__ == "__main__":
   pool = Pool(4)
   with open('file.txt') as source_file:
    # chunk the work into batches of 4 lines at a time
       results = pool.map(process_line, source_file, 4)

   print results
```

Import Error:
[image]

Comment: Is your file called threading.py? Try renaming it to something else. The multiprocessing module depends on the standard lib threading package.

Comment: @rsiemens: thanks. import error is resolved by renaming file. But now gettingTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample_test.py", line 18, in <module>
    results = pool.map(process_line, source_file, 4)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 250, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 554, in get
    raise self._value
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory